# Rotation of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, vectors

My linear algebra textbook only explained the rotation of a vector in a counterclockwise direction. I'm just wondering what happens if I rotate a vector in the clockwise direction? Do I solve such problems using the same method as for rotation in the anticlockwise direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you rotate by an angle $\phi$, the rotation matrix (around the $Z$-axis) becomes:

$$
M_z=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{\phi} & -\sin{\phi}& 0\\
\sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

You can also rotate by an angle $-\phi$. The matrix then becomes:
$$
M_z=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{\phi} & \sin{\phi}& 0\\
-\sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

because $\cos{(-\phi)}=\cos{\phi}$ and $\sin{(-\phi)} = -\sin{\phi}$. So you just replace $\phi$ by $-\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the scheme you're using has a parameter $\theta$ where you rotate $\theta$ radians clockwise if $\theta$ is positive, and that negative radians will instead carry out the clockwise rotation.

Alternatively, if you wanted to rotate $\theta$ radians clockwise, then you could just rotate $2\pi-\theta$ radians counterclockwise to get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$

Above is a rotation matrix in the plane, notice what we get when we change $\theta$ to $-\theta$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(-\theta) & -\sin(-\theta) \\\sin(-\theta) & \cos(-\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$

so that:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$